# Different values for sin(45) and cos(45) in python despite them being equivalent

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

I'm making a program that calculates distance moved of an object however when I run the program using 45 as an angle (sin45 and cos45 are equivalent) the output is different for vertical height and horizontal height

```
import math

angle = float(input("Enter Angle of Movement(In Degrees): "))
print("Angle is: ",angle,"°")

horizontal_distance = (abs(overall_distance*math.sin(90-angle)))
print("Horizontal Distance:",horizontal_distance,"m")

vertical_distance = (abs(overall_distance*math.cos(90-angle)))
print("Vertical Distance:",vertical_distance,"m")
```

Answer (score 5):

The input values for sine and cosine are in radians, not degrees.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i am working to a specification and one requirement is that user should input the angle in degrees. Is there any way around this? thanks again

Comment: Yeah, you can always convert the value from the input from degrees to radians before you calculate the trigonometric functions for it.

Comment: @HarrisonBowers there is simple way to do it. `from numpy import deg2rad` and use it like this: `deg2rad(angle_in_degrees)` (I think)

Comment: You can also just multiply the angle in degrees by `math.pi / 180`

Comment: even if the expression is in radian, sin and cos 45 may still be different because there's no way to represent pi exactly in floating-point, and because transcendental operations isn't required to be properly rounded in IEEE-754 [Why do sin(45) and cos(45) give different results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31509019/995714)

Answer (score 1):

The input is in radian units, not degree. Here's the documentation - https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html.

Instead, you should replace sin(90-angle) with sin(math.pi/2 - angle).

UPDATE:
Just saw your post about converting degree to radian. You can use math.radians(degree)

Comment: much appreciated :) im very new to python so i appreciate the help. EDIT: still seems to output different values for me even though they are equivalent

Comment: Can you write down the code which converts degree to radian and computing the sin of it?

Comment: Try replace "90-angle" with "math.pi/2 - math.radians(angle)"

Comment: I think i've got it now! Thank you so much for your help (and other people's comments). I appreciate you taking time to help a new user:)

Comment: Also note that the output of this: `print math.sin(math.radians(45)) == math.cos(math.radians(45));` returns `False`.  So yes, they are equivalent, but they are not the same!

Answer (score 0):

For the second question

```
import math
x = math.radians(float(input()))
y = math.radians(float(input()))
SIN = math.sin(x)
COS = math.cos(y)
print(x)
print(y)
print(SIN)
print(COS)


45 
45
0.7853981633974483
0.7853981633974483
0.7071067811865476
0.7071067811865476
```