# std::sin change in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/) includes the following description about [the return value of `std::sin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sin):

> The result may have little or no significance if the magnitude of arg
>   is large (until C++11)

I've tried to find information about this in the current C++ standard, but I've found nothing (maybe I missed it?). What has exactly been changed in C++11 this regard about `std::sin`?

Comment: There is no `std::sin` in C, so I removed that part. Don't confuse the two languages.

Comment: @Rakete1111: there are parts of the C++ standard which refer to the C standard, aren't they? (at least I have some memory that I've seen this - maybe I remember wrongly...)

Comment: Well yeah, but it is still the C++ standard, not the C one. [library.c](http://eel.is/c++draft/library.c)

Comment: `sin` can be calculated with the argument `mod 2 pi`, but for a large `double` number the least significant numbers are not significant. So `sin(5e100)` will probably not return the correct result: https://ideone.com/LORAwb

Comment: It is just an inevitable side-effect of sin() being periodic over 0..twopi.  The larger the argument, the fewer significant digits are left in the arg % twopi calculation.  The "until C++11" annotation strikes me as wildly optimistic and neither C99 nor C++11 say anything about it.  They can't.

Comment: @mch: yep, that's well understood :) The question is, has something changed in C++11? Is there something about this case in the standard?

Comment: in C standard: [`The result may have little or no significance if the magnitude of arg is large. (until C99)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/sin)

Comment: [related](/q/19644938), [related](/q/6665418), [related](/q/9423516), [related](/q/46711285)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C++11 switched the C standard reference from C89/C90 to C99. The original C standard used to state (quoted from a draft):

> The sin function computes the sine of x (measured in radians). A large magnitude argument may yield a result with little or no significance.

In C99, this text was dropped, and the description is now merely:

> The sin functions compute the sine of x (measured in radians).

I suspect the reason for dropping this is that C99 introduced the `__STDC_IEC_559__` macro, which implementations can define to document their compliance to that standard. According to [Standard for the sine of very large numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665418/standard-for-the-sine-of-very-large-numbers), it recommends (but does not require) correct results even for large magnitude arguments. The original C standard's text could be seen as weakening that recommendation.

Comment: As an aside, the classical paper for argument reduction of large inputs for trigonometric functions is Ng et al, ARGUMENT REDUCTION FOR HUGE ARGUMENTS: Good to the Last Bit, https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~phatak/645/supl/Ng-ArgReduction.pdf